# Как остановить resizable

Tags: jquery, javascript, ui

пишу функцию чтоб при дваном клике на элемент он становиться растягиваемым

```
$(".newElement").on('dblclick', function () {
            $(this).resizable({containment: "#contener"});
        });
```

здесь все работает, а как сделать чтоб при одинарном клике он прекращал быть растягиваемым?

```
$(".newElement").click(function () {
            $(this)??????;
        });
```

Кто знает как дописать следующию функцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(this).resizable('destroy');
```

Comment: а может еще подскажите как сделать чтоб рамка остовалось после того как прекратилось растягивания и убераласи по клику на элемент

            $(".newElement").on('dblclick', function () {
                $(this).css({'border':'2px dotted #000000'});
            });
   $(".newElement").click(function () {
                $(this).css({'border':'none'});
            });
            //показываем крестик при двойном клике на элемент
            $(".newElement").on('dblclick', function () {
                $(this).find('.delete').fadeIn(100);
            });